# setInterval again in 5 seconds after clearInterval button

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm doing a content slider that automatically cycles slides (by periodically calling the "next" function using `setInterval`)but stops when the user click on a prev/next buttons (by using `clearInterval` on the prev/next buttons). Is there a way to use `setInterval` again after a few seconds of clicking the button?

**Code:**

```
// start to automatically cycle slides
var cycleTimer = setInterval(function () {
   $scroll.trigger('next');
}, 450);

// set next/previous buttons as clearInterval triggers 
var $stopTriggers = $('img.right').add('img.left'); // left right

// function to stop auto-cycle
function stopCycle() {
   clearInterval(cycleTimer); 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your `setInterval` in a function and then call that function with `setTimeout()`.

The difference between `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` is that `setInterval()` calls your function repeatedly at each interval, while `setTimeout()` calls your function only once after the specified delay.

In the code below I've added a function `startCycle()`. Call that function to, well, start the cycle, both immediately so that it starts automatically and from a timeout set within your existing `stopCycle()` function.

```
var cycleTimer;

function startCycle() {
   cycleTimer = setInterval(function () {
      $scroll.trigger('next');
   }, 450);
}

// start to automatically cycle slides
startCycle();

// set next/previous buttons as clearInterval triggers 
var $stopTriggers = $('img.right').add('img.left'); // left right

// function to stop auto-cycle
function stopCycle() {
   clearInterval(cycleTimer);
   setTimeout(startCycle, 5000); // restart after 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Nice! It works! Thank you! Just needed to bind `stopCycle()` to the `$stopTriggers` by adding `$stopTriggers.bind('click.cycle', stopCycle);` and then I was good to go! Thank you for your help!